# web-server.js with apache-like DirectoryIndex behavior

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I am using the web-server.js node script to run a webserver on my local machine.
The behavior of web-server.js is to dump a complete file listing if a directory is requested.
instead I would like to emulate the apache DirectoryIndex where by if there is an index.html in the directory it will be served instead.

Comment: Perhaps it's worthwhile learning [Express](http://expressjs.com/). The Angular `web-server.js` script seems to be reinventing a lot of wheels.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I could not find the answer so here is my code that does it.

first I had to change the handleRequest function

```
if (stat.isDirectory()) {
        var indexFile = self.getDirectoryIndex_(path);
        if (indexFile)
            return self.sendFile_(req, res, indexFile);
        return self.sendDirectory_(req, res, path);
    }
```

and here is my implementation to getDirectoryIndex_

```
StaticServlet.prototype.getDirectoryIndex_ = function(path) {
  var result = null;
  var files = fs.readdirSync(path);

  files.forEach(function(fileName, index) {
      if (fileName.match(/^index\./gi)) {
          result = path + fileName;
          return false; //break foreach loop
      }
  });

  return result;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html  You can check for files with this.